# Besides people from Rome, what other Italians make frequent use of the word "mò" (meaning "now")?

Tags: word-choice, regional, adverbs, single-words

I would like to ask the following question: besides people from Rome, what other Italians make frequent use of the word "mò" (meaning "now")?

Thanks!

Comment: For instance, [Dante](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/mo/). :-)

Comment: @DaG, se metti quel commento fai sembrare come se 'mo' si usasse normalmente in Italia, cosa che non è vera perché, invero, mo si usa solo al Sud.

Comment: @ElberichSchneider: I am sorry if such a confusion arose. I only meant to point out a curious fact (Dante used *mo*, and more than once) and to give a useful link (that Treccani article clearly specifies that «oggi la parola è viva nelle regioni centro-merid.»).

Comment: E allora mettila una risposta, che l'OP è forestiero.

Comment: Funny, although I'm a rather fussy native speaker, I didn't know that _mo'_ can also be written without an apostrophe!

Comment: @iSar: I've seen your answer to this question and I think it's a pity that you deleted it. I think that simply you should reformulated it a bit because in the way it was it seemed more a question rather than an answer. It would be a good idea to add some examples of dialects or of regions of Italy that use the word "mo".

Comment: Yes, absolutely, that would be great! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nowadays the word *mo'* (with or without the apostrophe), is commonly used in the center and south of Italy (I'm a northern, so please correct me if I'm wrong!).
For instance, I heard it from people who live in Abruzzo and in Umbria, but also from people who live in Naples.

An example of its usage can be something like

> Ho visto il tuo messaggio mo'

that means "I just saw your text message", or

> Mo' chiamo Alessia

that is "I'm calling Alessia now".

Comment: So it can mean both "now" (adesso), as well as "just now" (appena adesso), perhaps accoding to where in the sentence the word is found? I didn't know that.

Comment: I think that the position of the word in the sentence doesn't have any particular influence in this case, since "mo" is used only in the spoken language and in an informal context. The second sentence could be rewritten as "Chiamo Alessia mo'." and the meaning won't change.

Comment: I cannot speak for other parts of Italy, but in Rome the examples with *mo'* at the end would sound unusual. One would say, in the two cases, «L'ho visto mo', il tuo messaggio» and, as given by ele_ctric, «Mo' chiamo Alessia».

Comment: I agree with DaG, although the following is possible (but I don't know where exactly in Italy): _Ho visto il tuo messaggio mo' mo'_

Comment: @WalterTross mo' mo' is "right now" but more like "in a second"

Comment: @Roberto: you mean that _lo faccio mo' mo'_ is more correct than _l'ho fatto mo' mo'_? I don't think so, but I may be wrong.

Comment: @WalterTross exactly. Imagine your wife asking you to do the dishes. "Lo faccio mo' mo'!" ...which usually actually means you're doing something else and would really like to finish it.

Answer (score -3):

Mo' è usato anche nelle Marche e deriverebbe dal latino "mox", "immediately"

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE!

Comment: Perché “immediately” in inglese? E comunque [“mo'” deriva da “modo”](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/mo_res-3aa5b880-0026-11de-9d89-0016357eee51).

Comment: @DaG Non credo che *mo'* nel senso di *adesso* *or ora*, com'è adoperato in certe parti d'Italia, derivi da *modo*; la derivazione da *mox* sembra in effetti più ragionevole. Tuttavia occorrerebbe qualche fonte più certa.

Comment: @egreg: In effetti il link che davo era sbagliato: quello giusto è [questo](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/mo/), con il “mo'” di cui stiamo parlando e la stessa origine da “modo”, l'avverbio latino che, nelle specificazioni temporali, significa esattamente “ora, adesso, subito” (cito dal Castiglioni-Mariotti, ma cf. anche [qui](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=modo&la=la&can=modo0#lexicon), al punto II.).